# Best way to move site from subdomain to root through cPanel?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, subdomain

I have an old Wordpress blog hosted on a subdomain (sub.mysite.com) with hundreds of posts.

The root domain is actually empty and redirected to the subdomain.

Now I want to move the site from the subdomain to the root domain.

I found some .htaccess examples like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirection seems to work if I clone or move the subdomain site into the root domain but, Is there an easier way? I mean, just like when you redirect from www. to non-www. and you only have one site installation. The site would be kept installed on subdomain folder but it would be accessed from root domain, is it possible?

Comment: How did you set up the subdomain?   To answer this question we'd need your virtual host configuration file or how it looks in cPanel.

Comment: In cPanel I just created de subdomain and installed Wordpress in it. The root index.php just has a 301 redirect to the subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) available, you could proxy all requests forward to the subdomain through your `.htaccess` file with the `[P]` flag.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe not the *best* way (the best way would be to move all the files and reset any links properly), but certainly the easiest.